# Configure the Db dynamically based on the request using spring bo

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am creating a application using spring boot. In this there will be a master db where all the users details and some other tables will exists. Now while am requesting to create  a user to the application using the webservice  its checks is the user exists in the MasterDb( user Table) or not. 
if exists the eg: "Google" user in the master database table. Then the application need to connect to the "Google" db and get the requested data. else it will create a "Google" db and its table using jdbc and it had to connect to  the Google db when next request comes with the "google" db name.

Answer (score 0):

A few points before getting started here:

1. It is generally considered a bad idea to have multiple databases in an application. Its better to have one database with multiple tables.
2. In your case, you should be having one single database, with multiple tables for each of the users. Basically, one table for keeping track if the user exists or not, and then one table for each user that exists.

One big issue with your approach of multiple databases is the database configuration management. Suppose, if you have 1000 users, you will have to manage 1000 configuration in your application. Instead, having one database configuration and multiple tables is more manageable. There is a high chance of your application design being flawed if you're trying to create and manage hundereds of database configuration.

Based on the information provided in the question and comments, you can look into using JDBCTemplate in your Spring App. You can configure multiple data sources based on given dynamic parameters and thus connect to multiple databases. Check [Spring MVC with JDBC Template](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example). However, you will need to tweak the code given in this tutorial to fit multiple data sources within your app.

Comment: is there any possibilities to connect to  'newDbs' like old JDBC style and use the JPA repositories to fetch the data.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple db configurations. However, you need to specify the connection string parameters in advance(either in xml or java config) to connect to the 'newDbs'. The Link shared in the answer should help you have multiple db configs, but yes, this is very much possible.

Comment: In the above answer multiple Db configurations had happened at the starting of the application it self.
In my case the to configure the DB  at starting of the application , The DB may not be exist. The New DB is Created Dynamically through a request to the application using the JDBC code. Now once the DB is created the User should able to connect to 'newDb' .
Am not understanding now how to configure these newly created Db to connect it.
I need something like to add all the db names to a list dynamically and for these list the connection has to arrange.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification. As I understand, you have a dynamic db name(and possibly the db credentials among other things). 
You can use JDBCTemplate in your Spring App to configure a dataSource based on the given dynamic parameters and then connect to the db in a specific DAO Implementation Layer. Check [Spring MVC with JDBCTemplate] (http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example)
Updated my answer to reflect the same